# How to find the matrix $A^n$, given an symbolic square matrix $A$

Tags: matrix, symbolic

First post here, I hope there's not too much trouble.

I want to compute $A^n$ like the following example:[image]

An simple matlab code solved this problem if $A$ is diagonalizable. (you can see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915626/matlab-function-that-computes-an-being-a-an-square-matrix-and-n-an-natur/1915762#1915762)

But what I need is to compute this power of a matrix if the matrix has symbolic and numerical entries like:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2p_{11} & p_{12} \\ 2/p_{21} & 1+p_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

which in general cannot be assumed diagonalizable.

So, what can I do here?

Comment: How about `MatrixPower`? With it you can do exactly what you want: calculate the power of an abitrary matrix.

Comment: it works for symbolic inputs? I am sorry, I dont have the software yet, tomorrow I will try this.

Comment: Almost everything without an `N` infront of it works with symbolic input. `MatrixPower` does, I tried it. The expressions get very nasty and long but it does the job as well as possible I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = {{0, 1}, {-1/6, 5/6}};

MatrixPower[A, n]

(*  {{-2^(1 - n) + 3^(1 - n), 3 2^(1 - n) - 2 3^(1 - n)}, {-2^-n + 3^-n, 
  3 2^-n - 2 3^-n}}  *)

Format[p[m_, n_]] := Subscript[p, StringJoin[ToString /@ {m, n}]]

A = {{2 p[1, 1], p[1, 2]}, {2/p[2, 1], 1 + p[2, 2]}};

MatrixPower[A, n] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: Never knew you could put an n in there to get the general term. +1